# Using _.extend in Function prototype

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, prototype, extend

I'm seeing a lot of this these days:

```
function Dog () {
    this.name = 'Fido';
}

_.extend(Dog.prototype, {
    bark: function() {
        return 'BARK, BARK!'
    },
    soilChothingWithDirtyPaws: function () {
        // Some intricated logic here
        return 'There, I did it!';
    }
});
```

But is the result different from the code below?

```
function Dog () {
    this.name = 'Fido';
}
Dog.prototype = {
    bark: function() {
        return 'BARK, BARK!'
    },
    soilChothingWithDirtyPaws: function () {
        // Some intricated logic here
        return 'There, I did it!';
    }
}
```

I know what underscore's [extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function is supposed to do, but I don't really get the point of doing this in the object's prototype -  when you could do this with plain old vanilla JS, that means, I can't see why a man in the middle is needed here. 
I wonder if I'm missing something really neat.

Does that bring any good at all?

It would be really nice if somebody clear things out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining a Javascript prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474390/defining-a-javascript-prototype)

Comment: @Bergi It's not a duplicate at all, because the aforementioned question doesn't involve underscore's _.extend() method. My question is if is there any benefit of using it instead of plain prototypes and not about how to use js prototypes.

Comment: Well, I though you knew that `_.extend(Dog.prototype, {bark: function() {…}});` is equal to `Dog.prototype.bark = function() {…};`. I even mentioned `extend` in my answer there (which is about extending vs overwriting prototypes, not about underscore extend).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`_.extend`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L870) is defined like this,

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
    each(slice.call(arguments, 1), function(source) {
        if (source) {
            for (var prop in source) {
                obj[prop] = source[prop];
            }
        }
    });
    return obj;
};
```

All it does is, iterate over the attributes of all the elements from the argument at index 1 till the end and add it to the first argument passed to it.

So, technically, what you have done will have the same effect, but *with one subtle difference.*

When you use `_.extend`, you are augmenting the `Dog.prototype` object, when you assign to it (like in your second example), you are replacing the `Dog.prototype` object with some other object.

Comment: The difference isn't that subtle, `Dog.prototype.constructor` will have a different value!