# What's the JavaScript's Object.prototype behavior?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, javascript-objects

I ran into a strange snippet of code, which I cannot understand at all, here it is:

```
var obj = function() {};
obj.prototype.x = 5;

var instance1 = new obj();

obj.prototype = {y: 6};

var instance2 = new obj();

console.log(instance1.x, instance1.y, instance2.x, instance2.y);
// 5, undefined, undefined, 6
```

**Now, the questions are:**

1. Why is this logging `5, undefined, undefined, 6` instead of `undefined, 6, undefined, 6`?
2. Why replacing the prototype is not changing the prototype of all the instances of the object, as it would usually do?
3. What is the V8 engine doing, step by step, in this code?
4. EDIT: **How would I go about changing the prototype of ALL the instances?**

Every explanation is appreciated.

Comment: instance1 will have a reference to the initial prototype object through \_\_proto\_\_ property. So, when you change the prototype object, instance1 already has the old reference. instance2.__proto__ gets a reference to the new prototype object.

Comment: *How would I go about changing the prototype of ALL the instances*: use `obj.prototype.y = 6`, or (once, before any instantiation) `obj.prototype = {x: 5, y: 6}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining a Javascript prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17474390/1048572)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [ECMA Script 5 specifications](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.5.2),

> The value of the `prototype` property is used to initialise the `[[Prototype]]` internal property of a newly created object before the Function object is invoked as a constructor for that newly created object.

It is clear that `prototype` is just to initialize the `[[Prototype]]` property. When we create an object, `[[Prototype]]` is set as the constructor function's `prototype` object and the prototype chain is established. In your case, when you do

```
var obj = function() {};
obj.prototype.x = 5;

var instance1 = new obj();
```

the `[[Prototype]]` looks like this

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance1));
# { x: 5 }
```

*(Yes, you can access the `[[Prototype]]` with `Object.getPrototypeOf` function)*

So, when JS Engine looks for `x` in `instance1`, it finds the value as `5` and since `y` is not defined, it uses `undefined`.

In the second case,

```
obj.prototype = {y: 6};

var instance2 = new obj();
```

you are changing the `prototype` object of `obj`, so that the new objects constructed with this functions will use the new object assigned to it. So, `[[Prototype]]` looks like this, for `instance2`

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance2));
# { y: 6 }
```

That is why, `instance2` couldn't find `x` in it, but `y`.

---

To answer the updated question,

> EDIT: How would I go about changing the prototype of ALL the instances?

You can change, the prototype of the old object with `Object.setPrototypeOf`, like this

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(instance1, {
    y: 6
});
```

Since, this makes the `[[Prototype]]` of `instance1` different from `instance2`, we can just update the constructor function's `prototype` object, like this

```
delete obj.prototype.x;
obj.prototype.y = 6;
```

Now, we havn't changed the internal property of both `instance1` and `instance2`. We can check that like this

```
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(instance2));
# true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance1) === obj.prototype);
# true
```

**Note:** The convention is to name the constructor functions with the initial letter a capital letter.

Comment: I edited my question, have you got an explanation to the point #4? If so, edit your answer! Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer and for quoting the specifications!

Answer (score 9):

**Explanation**

So first, your two lines of code create a function, `obj`, and assign to it's prototype `{x: 5}`.

When you create an instance of this object, it seems to have an internal reference to the prototype that existed when it was `new`'d.

After this, you reassign the prototype to `{y: 6}` which does not affect the `instance1` internal reference to the first prototype.

Then when you create `instance2` it has an internal reference to the 2nd prototype and therefore, logging them will produce `5, undefined, undefined, 6`.

**#4**

You could, rather than reassign the prototype to a new object:

```
obj.prototype = {y: 6};
```

Modify the prototype instead:

```
delete obj.prototype.x; // Setting to undefined should produce same behaviour
obj.prototype.y = 6;
```

This will produce the output: `undefined, 6, undefined, 6`

I have tested this with http://jsfiddle.net/9j3260gp/ on Chrome and Firefox latest versions on Windows.

Comment: I edited my question, have you got an explanation to the point #4? If so, edit your answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @thefourtheye It seemed to work on Chrome when I ran it on jsFiddle. I believe there is only one ``prototype`` object and every instance, references it. Therefore, editing the object should allow all instances to access the modified version.

Comment: @thefourtheye Added jsFiddle test, it seems to work, so I'm not sure. :S

Comment: @Winestone Ah, right... I didn't read your answer properly... This works because, `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(instance1) === obj.prototype);`. Sorry for the trouble :-)

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Why is this logging `5`, `undefined`, `undefined`, `6` instead of `undefined`, `6`, `undefined`, `6`?
> 2. Why replacing the prototype is not changing the prototype of all the instances of the object, as it would usually do?

Fundamentally, this comes down to the fact that object references are values, rather like numbers, that tell the JavaScript engine (V8 in your case) where the object is in memory. When you copy a value, you do just that: You *copy* the value. Copying an object reference makes a copy of the reference (not the object), and doesn't in any way tie the destination of that value to the source of the value, anymore than this ties `b` to `a`:

```
var a = 5;
var b = a;
a = 6;
console.log(b, a); // 5, 6
```

And so, your code logs what it logs, and doesn't change `instance1`'s prototype, for the same reason this code logs that same thing and doesn't change the value of `instance1.p`:

```js
var foo = {x: 5};
var instance1 = {p: foo};

foo = {y: 6};

var instance2 = {p: foo};

console.log(instance1.p.x, instance1.p.y, instance2.p.x, instance2.p.y);
```

Let's throw some ASCII-art (well, Unicode-art) at it, which will also answer:

> 3. What is the V8 engine doing, step by step, in this code?

After you run this:

```
var obj = function() {};
obj.prototype.x = 5;

var instance1 = new obj();
```

...you have something roughly like this in memory (ignoring some details):

```
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+             
                 |     (function)      |             
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+             
obj<Ref55461>−−−>| prototype<Ref32156> |−−−−−−−−−−−+
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+            \ 
                                                     \     
                                                      \    
                                                       \   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                        +−>| (object) |
                                                       /   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                      /    | x<5>     |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    /     +−−−−−−−−−−+
                      |         (object)        |   /
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  /
instance1<Ref86545>−−>| [[Prototype]]<Ref32156> |−+
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Since object references are values, and assignment always *copies* values, when V8 (or any other engine) creates `instance1`, it *copies* the value from `obj.prototype` (shown here conceptually as `<Ref32156>`) to `instance1`'s `[[Prototype]]` internal slot.

Then, when you do

```
obj.prototype = {y: 6};
```

...you're changing the value in `obj.prototype` (shown here as changing `<Ref32156>` to `<Ref77458>`), but that has no effect on the value (`<Ref32156>`) in `instance1`'s `[[Prototype]]` slot:

```
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   
                 |     (function)      |                   
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   +−−−−−−−−−−+
obj<Ref55461>−−−>| prototype<Ref77458> |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−>| (object) |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                           | y<6>     |
                                                           +−−−−−−−−−−+

                                                           +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                        +−>| (object) |
                                                       /   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                      /    | x<5>     |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    /     +−−−−−−−−−−+
                      |         (object)        |   /
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  /
instance1<Ref86545>−−>| [[Prototype]]<Ref32156> |−+
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...and so consequently, when you do

```
var instance2 = new obj();
```

...you have:

```
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   
                 |     (function)      |                   
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                   +−−−−−−−−−−+
obj<Ref55461>−−−>| prototype<Ref77458> |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−>| (object) |
                 +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+               /   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                      /    | y<6>     |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    /     +−−−−−−−−−−+
                      |         (object)        |   /      
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  /       
instance2<Ref98465>−−>| [[Prototype]]<Ref77458> |−+        +−−−−−−−−−−+
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+       +−>| (object) |
                                                       /   +−−−−−−−−−−+
                                                      /    | x<5>     |
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+    /     +−−−−−−−−−−+
                      |         (object)        |   /
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  /
instance1<Ref86545>−−>| [[Prototype]]<Ref32156> |−+
                      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

...which explains the `console.log` result.

> 5. EDIT: How would I go about changing the prototype of ALL the instances?

If you want to actually change what object they're using as their prototype, you can only do that if you have a reference to the instance(s) you want to change, and only on a JavaScript engine supporting ES2015 features, by using [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object.setprototypeof) or (in a web browser environment, and if the object ultimately inherits from `Object.prototype`) via the [`__proto__` accessor property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__) (not recommended):

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(instance1, obj.prototype);
```

`setPrototypeOf` changes the value of the `[[Prototype]]` internal slot in the object (as does setting `__proto__`, if the object has it).

You can't do it if you don't have access to the instances.

I don't think you do, given the question, but if you just want to change the *state* of the object they use as their prototype (perhaps by adding `y`), you can of course just set properties on it, and because JavaScript's prototypical inheritance is "live" (there's a live link back to the prototype from an instance), you can then access those properties on any instance that inherits from the prototype, even if they were created before you made the change:

```
var Example = function() { };
Example.prototype.x = 5;

var instance1 = new Example();
console.log(instance1.x, instance1.y); // 5, undefined

Example.prototype.y = 6;
console.log(instance1.x, instance1.y); // 5, 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation with relative ASCII art, really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

prototype is a feature which is paired with new behind the scenes. It applies to all instances of that function used with new. In the first example, you append .x = 5 to the prototype, and the instance you create has .x =5 as a value. Later you modify the prototype to be a new object. Now this is the prototype which is used in any new instances. So this is why the first instance only has .x = 5, and the second only has .y = 6

Answer (score 1):

The prototype of instances do not reference the class, instead they reference the prototype object itself. This will become clear when you try `Object.getPrototypeOf()` to see which prototype object the instance references.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(instance1)
Object { x: 5, 1 more… }

Object.getPrototypeOf(instance2)
Object { y: 6 }
```

This field `getPrototypeOf` references is supposed to be an internal one which exists for each instance. Before `getPrototypeOf` existed, you could get this via `__proto__`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `instance1` is already created. The `new` keyword creates new object by executing a constructor function, which in your case is `obj`.

Because you changed the prototype after the initialization of the first instance, you do not have the same state (e.g. the prototype) of the constructor anymore and can't make the same object. But the created ones are still there, referencing to the old prototype.

When you use the `obj` constructor again you are making another object which could be very roughly translated to the classical type of inheritance's terminology as instance of another class.

**Edit: #4**
This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doy3g1fh/
shows that

```
obj.prototype.y=6
```

succeeds in changing all existing objects. So the answer obviously is that you shouldn't assign new object as prototype but just modify the current prototype.

Comment: I edited my question, have you got an explanation to the point #4? If so, edit your answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: In fact, they are both initialised by the same constructor function. But created from different prototype objects.