# Setting the prototype has to be done before the first call to constructor function. But why...?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am playing with inheritance in JavaScript (in the ES5 way).

Here I am creating 3 instances of Dog with the code below.
But my first `Dog` instance is not properly initialized.

I noticed that when the execution enters the first call to `Animal` (from line `// *`), it does not detect my first `Dog` as an `Animal`?! That seems to cause the problem. Why? I have already set the `Dog.prototype` before entering the Animal function.

Now... if I uncomment line `// ***` then even my first Dog is properly initialized.
Seems that it's related to the order in which I call `Dog.prototype =` and `new Dog`.

Why is it not OK to set `Dog.prototype =` inside the first call to the `Dog` constructor function?!
Why does it have to be done before I call `new Dog` for the first time?
There seems to be some deep reason for this, but I don't know it.

Also, how do I fix this? What is the best way? I tried returning `this` from `Animal` but that does not help. Note that... I want to keep these "secure calls" there.

```
    function Animal (name, energy) {
        if (!(this instanceof Animal)){
            console.log("Secure call to Animal()");
            return new Animal(name, energy);
        }
        this.name = name;
        this.energy = energy;

        // return this;
    }

    // Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); // *** 

    function Dog (name, energy, breed) {

        if (!(this instanceof Dog)){
            console.log("Secure call to Dog()");
            return new Dog(name, energy, breed);
        }
        this.x = "DOG";
        if (Dog.prototype.constructor !== Animal){
            console.log("Setting Dog.prototype");
            Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
            // Dog.prototype = new Animal();
        }
        Animal.call(this, name, energy); // * 
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    var d1 = new Dog("Johnie", 20, "b1");
    var d2 = new Dog("Mike", 10, "b1");
    var d3 = new Dog("Ruth", 30, "b1");
```

Comment: Because `Dog.prototype` is evaluated when you use `new`, *before* the constructor is applied to the new instance.

Comment: "*how do I fix this? What is the best way?*" - uncommenting the line that is outside of the `Dog` constructor, and removing the stuff from inside the function. You can keep the "secure calls" that guards against forgetting `new`.

Comment: @Bergi Hm... Not sure who evaluates it and when... But even so... OK... but why is this check failing `(!(this instanceof Animal))` during the initialization of the 1st `Dog` ?! At that point `Dog.prototype` is already set.

Comment: @peter.petrov Actually at that point `this` is not `instanceof Animal` nor `instanceof Dog`. (I didn't really figure out why)

Comment: @Cristy It is instance of Dog but not of Animal, that's what my tests show. I mean at the moment when `(!(this instanceof Animal))` is evaluated.

Comment: @peter.petrov Shows false for me: https://jsfiddle.net/rhjmay1v/

Comment: @peter.petrov The `new` operator itself evaluates it, to create the new object with the right inheritance chain. And at that point, `Dog.prototype` still is the standard empty prototype object, it does not inherit from `Animal.prototype`, as that line hasn't yet executed when you're placing it inside the constructor (which you should not do!).

Comment: @Cristy Oh... but then why is it instance of Dog earlier. Note that this code is not getting executed `Secure call to Dog()` So it's an instance of Dog earlier but seems it's lost somehow later.

Comment: @Cristy If you are confused about `instanceof`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568239/javascriptinstanceof-operator) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324395/whats-the-javascripts-object-prototype-behavior). Again, don't assign to `.prototype` after invoking `new`.

Comment: @Bergi But that's exactly my point - why is it not OK to modify the inheritance chain later?! Something seems illogical/weird here...

Comment: @peter.petrov Because you don't *modify* the inheritance chain (as `Object.setPrototypeOf` would), but you *replace* it. And it doesn't take effect retroactively on objects that inherit from the old prototype. Please have a look at the duplicate and the other links.

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand... I will think some more.

Comment: @Bergi So... are we saying that when I create an object, the object itself makes a copy of what the constructor function's prototype was at the moment of the object creation? And from then on, JS uses that copy to determine if my object is `instanceof` something else. I thought JS would use the `Dog.prototype` master copy for such checks. So basically me setting Dog.prototype later has no effect. Is that what it's all about? About... a stale copy of the prototype? I still find it weird. So basically we need to setup `Dog.prototype` completely BEFORE we start creating any instances of `Dog`.

Comment: @peter.petrov It's not a copy, but a link - a reference to the object. You can access it with `Object.getPrototypeOf(d1)`. And yes, it's stale, it's not the current value of `Dog.prototype`. In contrast, `Object.getPrototypeOf(d2) === Dog.prototype`.

Comment: @peter.petrov "*So basically we need to setup `Dog.prototype` completely BEFORE we start creating any instances of `Dog`*" - that's what I've been telling you all the time, and that's what the standard ES5 pattern (the commented-out code) does :-)

Comment: @Bergi OK, I think I got it. Thanks.