# Inheritance and the prototype chain: reassigning the Constructor.prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, instance

I'm trying to improve my knowledge on object, constructors, prototype and all that stuff related to objects in JS. I was reading a post on MDN about inheritance and the prototype chain and I came across this explanation about why you should not reassign the Constructor.prototype after you created the instances. I cannot understand what those two reasons mean:

```
function Box(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
Box.prototype.getValue = function () {
  return this.value;
};
const box = new Box(1);

// Mutate Box.prototype after an instance has already been created
Box.prototype.getValue = function () {
  return this.value + 1;
};
box.getValue(); // 2
```

Their explanation:

A corollary is, *re-assigning* `Constructor.prototype` (`Constructor.prototype = ...`) is a bad idea for two reasons:

- The `[[Prototype]]` of instances created before the reassignment is now referencing a different object from the `[[Prototype]]` of instances created after the reassignment — mutating one's `[[Prototype]]` no longer mutates the other.
- Unless you manually re-set the `constructor` property, the constructor function can no longer be traced from `instance.constructor`, which may break user expectation. Some built-in operations will read the `constructor` property as well, and if it is not set, they may not work as expected.

Comment: Your code does "*Mutate Box.prototype*", as the comment explains, it does not do `Constructor.prototype = …` - so what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: Please link the mdn page you were reading

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: So, Box.prototype is just the prototype of the constructor fucntion Box. Besides that you can change the prototype of the Constructor, the constructor function itself? What I cannot understand Constructor, that they are refering to, and Box are two different things?

Comment: I come back after I read the answer that @FelixKling provided below. I got the idea. I now understand that `Constructor.prototype` is indeed the `Box.prototype`. The idea of `Box.prototype = ...` represents that the prototype of the Box will be another object. The idea of `Box.prototype.someMethod = ...` is to mutate the prototype of the Box, but not changing the prototype, `Box.prototype` will remain the same and the constructor will not be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article is referring to this behavior:

```js
function Box(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
Box.prototype.getValue = function () {
  return this.value;
};
const box1 = new Box(1);

// Mutate Box.prototype after an instance has already been created
Box.prototype = {
  getValue() {
    return this.value + 42;
  }
}

const box2 = new Box(1);

console.log(box1.getValue()); // 2
console.log(box2.getValue()); // 43
```

If you assign a new value to `Box.prototype` then only newly created instances will have this new value as their prototype. Mutating the existing prototype object as in your example is not a problem (but still not common).

> Unless you manually re-set the `constructor` property, the constructor function can no longer be traced from `instance.constructor` ...

Compare the following

```js
function Box(value) {
  this.value = value;
}
const box1 = new Box(1);
console.log('box1.constructor === Box:', box1.constructor === Box);

Box.prototype = {
  getValue() {
    return this.value + 42;
  }
}

const box2 = new Box(1);
console.log('box2.constructor === Box:', box2.constructor === Box);

Box.prototype = {
  constructor: Box,
  getValue() {
    return this.value + 42;
  }
}

const box3 = new Box(1);
console.log('box3.constructor === Box:', box3.constructor === Box);
```

Unless `constructor` is explicitly set after assigning to `Box.prototype`, `box.constructor` does not refer to `Box`.

---

This might useful:

- [Defining a Javascript prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474390/defining-a-javascript-prototype)
- [What's the JavaScript's Object.prototype behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324395/whats-the-javascripts-object-prototype-behavior)
- [JavaScript: instanceof operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14568239/javascriptinstanceof-operator)

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now what the idea was. I think that I understand a little bit more about how the prototype is related to the constructor function which in the first place was not the idea of the post, but I'm glad that I did. Thank you so much, again! :)