# AngularJS how is a scope $id's value set? Doesn't seem to be incremental.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to further investigate the scope hierarchy in AngularJS. Recently, I've been paying close attention to the scope.$id numbering—and I've noticed that the value applied to a scope's `$id` isn't applied in an incremental manner. For example:

```
<html ng-app="app">
    <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
         <!-- ngInclude: 'notifications.tpl.html' -->
         <!-- ngInclude: 'otherTpl.tpl.html' -->
          <div ng-include="someView.tpl.html">
          <ui-view></ui-view>
     </body>
</html>
```

This tree mirrors that of my DOM, where the `html` element has a scope `$id` of 1, `body` has an `$id` of 2, and the `ng-include` has a scope `$id` of 6, which doesn't seem to make much sense sequentially.

How are these `id` numbers determined? Does it matter at all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The id algorithm is:

```
function HashMap(array, isolatedUid) {
  if (isolatedUid) {
    /* Initialize uid to zero for the rootscope */
    var uid = 0;
    this.nextUid = function() {
      return ++uid;
    /* Increment the id */
    };
  }
  forEach(array, this.put, this);
}
```

The scope algorithm is:

```
        if (isolate) {
          child = new Scope();
          /* Increment when a directive which uses isolate scope is created */
          child.$root = this.$root;
        } else {
          // Only create a child scope class if somebody asks for one,
          // but cache it to allow the VM to optimize lookups.
          if (!this.$$ChildScope) {
            this.$$ChildScope = createChildScopeClass(this);
          }
          /* Increment when a directive which uses child scope is created */
          child = new this.$$ChildScope();
        }
```

> If you find that your code is now throwing a $compile:multidir error, check that you do not have directives on the same element that are trying to request both an isolate and a non-isolate scope and fix your code.
>
> If your code depends on this behavior (non-isolate directive needs to access state from within the isolate scope), change the isolate directive to use scope locals to pass these explicitly.
>
> scope.$new() takes one argument - a boolean indicating if the newly-created child scope should be isolated (not prototypically inheriting from the current scope). Previously the first argument was reference to the controller constructor, but because of the scope/controller separation the controllers should be instantiated via the $controller service.

**References**

- [What is the difference between $scope.$root and $rootScope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216441/1113772)
- [Why assign Something to Something.prototype.constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703896/1113772)
- [Adding clarity to scope inheritance in Angular](http://jonathancreamer.com/adding-clarity-to-scope-inheritance-in-angular/)
- [AngularJS Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
- [$compile throws error inconsistently if isolated-scope directive's priority is set/unset](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4402)
- [Isolate scope weird behavior based on directive's name](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12215)
- [fix($compile): fix missing error handling when new-scope directive is applied before isolated-scope directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4421)
- [fix($compile): throw error when requesting new and isolate scopes (async)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/12217)
- [controllerAs in directives doesn't play well with isolate scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7635)
- [feat($rootScope): adds $onRootScope method](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5507)
- [Using prototypal inheritance for AngularJS controllers and services](https://andywalpole.me/#!/blog/140067/using-prototypal-inheritance-angularjs-controllers-services)