# declare javascript static methods in a more concise way

Tags: javascript, oop

When I'm declaring instance methods in JS I often use this syntax:

```
var MyObj = function (p1) {
    this.p1 = p1;    
};

MyObj.prototype = {
    method1: function() {},
    method2: function() {},
    method2: function() {}
};
```

Is there a similar way to declare "static" methods instead of doing this:

```
MyObj.static1 = function() {
};

MyObj.static2 = function() {
};

MyObj.static3 = function() {
};
```

Comment: Just a note, you don't wanna completely override the prototype, you might lose Object heritage for it; just assign each separately

Comment: You could use the same syntax that you used for the prototype definition, `MyObj = {static1 : function(){...}, }`

Comment: @Hacketo, that would turn the constructor function into a (non-callable) object literal. So I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi OP want to keep the "constructor" function ? Then static methods should be declared in an other namespace

Comment: @Hacketo, yes, they only want to add static methods. It is perfectly legitimate to have static methods as members of the constructor function instead of "another namespace".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi of course but OP want to avoid this way `MyObj.static3 = function() {};`

Comment: @Hacketo, indeed, that's why the solution is `Object.assign()` (if your target browsers support ES6), or `$.extend()` if you're into jQuery, or a polyfill of some sort (like in aduch's answer).

Comment: I dislike modifying the `prototype` directly and prefer to do it all in the "constructor." Also, I think the *best* way for static methods is what you're already doing.

Comment: No support to ES6 and I'd like to aviod external libs of any sort. So I'll stick with the current syntax. I just wanted to make sure that there ins't a more concise way to declare them

Comment: Notice that even [for declaring prototype methods you shouldn't use this syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17474390/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is doing it in two steps:

```
var staticMethods = {
    static1: function () {
    },
    static2: function () {
    },
    static3: function () {
    }
};
```

Then use this `function`

```
function registerStaticMethods(aClass, staticMethods) {
    for (var methodName in staticMethods) {
        aClass[methodName] = staticMethods[methodName];
    }
}
```

You would use it like this

```
registerStaticMethods(MyObj, staticMethods);
```