# Javascript object methods prototype

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

What is the diference in the below aproachs. Which is the best way?

```
    var obj;
        obj = function () {

        }
        obj.prototype = {
         getName: function () {
         console.log("my name");
        }
     }
```

and this

```
 var obj;
    obj = function () {

    }
    obj.getName.prototype = {
    console.log("my name");
    }
```

Are both the same?

Comment: Well, just try it out. The second one throws an exception, so it's obviously not the same.

Answer (score 1):

With first one.

You are overwriting complete prototype object with new one.So,existing method and properties are get removed because of this assignment.

With Second one

You are assigning new method and  not removing existing method and properties.

**EDIT :**

The second one should be like this

```
obj.prototype.getName = function(){
}
```

Comment: The second on is just a syntax error. (And if you add `function()`, it's still a type error)

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same, and valid way to do it would be the first way.

Perhaps what you wanted to ask instead was the difference between these:

```
function() Obj {}

Obj.prototype.getName = function() {
       console.log("my name");
};

var obj = new Obj;
```

vs this

```
function() Obj {
  this.getName = function() {
     console.log("my name");
  };
}

var obj = new Obj;
```

well the answer is both are valid, first one adds function to prototype chain and second one adds to instance of the function.

Let's start with second one, simpler. After you run the code `obj` will have function name getName Attached to itself. `obj.getName()` will call the method on `obj`.

Whereas in first one when you call `obj.getName()`, the js compiler will look at `obj` for method `getName` and it will not be found there, so it will try look it up the chain. All objects in js have `__proto__` property. Where another object is. When you create object trhough a function using `new` keyword, resulted object's `__proto__` is set to fucntion's prototype.

The advantage of delegating functions like this is that say you make 30 objects with this function then there wont be 30 getName methods as well. Instead, all object will still be referencing to prototype object which will have the `getName` method. So there will be 30 references.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not the same.

The Code you posted is not valid JavaScript. And raises a SyntaxError.
I can only assume you ment to ask which one of the following is the "better" way of assinging properties to an Object Prototype:

```
var foo = {}
foo.prototype = {
   getName: function(){}
}
```

vs:

```
var foo = {}
foo.prototype = {}
foo.prototype.getName = function(){}
```

The first approach is better since you are not re-assinging a new object to the prototype - it would remove all properties that might have existed.
So the first one is considered better.

Comment: (actually [the first one *is* better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474390/defining-a-javascript-prototype))