# Why does `.constructor` point to `object` in this case?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

In the example below:

```
var A = function() {};
var a = new A();
var b = new A();
A.prototype.member1 = 10;

A.prototype = {}
var c = new A();
```

Now the `a.constructor` and `b.constructor` are both pointing to `function A`, which is expected.
However, `c.constructor` is pointing to a void `object`.

What is the rationale behind this? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474390/defining-a-javascript-prototype

Comment: @RobG `Object.prototype.constructor == Object` is what he means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now the a.constructor and b.constructor are both pointing to function
>   A, which is expected. However, c.constructor is pointing to a void
>   object.
>   *a* and *b* both have the original *A.prototype* object as their internal `[[Prototype]]`, which has a constructor property referencing *A*. So when you do:
>
> What is the rationale behind this? Thanks.

```
a.constructor
```

it is the inherited *constructor* property that is used.

You then replace the original prototype object with a new, "empty" object that doesn't have a *constructor* property. Replacing the constructor's prototype does not change the internal `[[Prototype]]` of existing instances, they still reference the object that was the prototype at the time they were constructed.

The new object will only be used as the `[[Prototype]]` for new instances, so when you construct *c*, it's internal `[[Prototype]]` is this new object that has no *constructor* property, so it continues along the `[[Prototype]]` chain until a *constructor* property is found on *Object.prototoype*, which references the *Object* constructor.

```js
var A = function() {};
var a = new A();
var b = new A();

A.prototype.member1 = 10;

// Replace A.prototype
A.prototype = {}
var c = new A();

// a still uses original prototype, so inherits member1
console.log(a.member1); // 10

// c uses the plain object, so doesn't have member1 property
console.log(c.member1); // undefined

// c inherits constructor property from Object.prototype, so
// references Object constructor
console.log(c.constructor === Object); // true
```

Comment: I'm getting `Object` for `c.constructor`, not `undefined`

Comment: @Bergi—ah yes, of course, it's falling through to Object.prototype… fixed.