# Prototyped properties on ECMA6 classes

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

Take the following code:

```js
function OldSchool() {}

OldSchool.prototype = {
  foo: "bar",
};

class NewSchool {
  foo = "bar";
}

let oldSchool = new OldSchool,
    newSchool = new NewSchool;

// false, true
console.log(
  oldSchool.hasOwnProperty("foo"),
  newSchool.hasOwnProperty("foo")
);

// 'bar', 'bar'
console.log(
  oldSchool.foo, newSchool.foo
);
```

How would I rewrite `NewSchool` to have the same prototyping behavior as `OldSchool`?

EDIT: The following does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OldSchool() {}

    OldSchool.prototype = {
        foo: "bar",
    };

    class NewSchool {}

    NewSchool.prototype = {
        foo: "bar",
    };

    let oldSchool = new OldSchool,
        newSchool = new NewSchool;

    // false, true
    console.log(
        oldSchool.hasOwnProperty("foo"),
        newSchool.hasOwnProperty("foo")
    );

    // 'bar', undefined
    console.log(
        oldSchool.foo, newSchool.foo
    );

</script>
```

Comment: Make it private. I.e., `class NewSchool { #foo = "bar"; }`

Comment: @HereticMonkey question updated

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't see how that is equivalent to putting the property on the prototype

Comment: @Bergi That wasn't the (original) question.

Comment: @Dan Use strict mode to see the mistake. [Don't attempt to overwrite `.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474390/defining-a-javascript-prototype), but add a new property to the existing prototype object: `NewSchool.prototype.foo = "bar";`

Comment: What about `Object.assign(NewSchool.prototype, {foo: 'bar'})`?

Comment: @Dan Same thing

Comment: Okay, apparently VS Code intellisense prefers `NewSchool.prototype.foo = "bar"`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Private Instance Fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_fields)? Here is an example:

```js
function OldSchool() {}

OldSchool.prototype = {
  foo: "bar",
};

class NewSchool {
  #foo = "bar";

  get foo() {
      return this.#foo;
  }
}

let oldSchool = new OldSchool,
    newSchool = new NewSchool;

// false, false
console.log(
  oldSchool.hasOwnProperty("foo"),
  newSchool.hasOwnProperty("foo")
);

// 'bar', 'bar'
console.log(
  oldSchool.foo, newSchool.foo
);
```

Comment: Question updated

Comment: @Dan Answer updated